# Vote to close is missing a spam option

Tags: discussion

When I saw the contents of the question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/how-to-create-3-dimensional-effective-game-in-java it was immediatly clear that it was a spam message, but when I voted to close I couldn't find any spam option, so I chose the off-topic option which others had used as well.

There is the flag as spam option though, but I'm not sure how close votes and flagging are related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spam should be deleted, not closed. Deletions are done by moderators, informed by flags. Closures are done by the whole (high-rep) community, and can be undone by the community if there's disagreement or the question is fixed.

As shown in that question, you can hasten the deletion process to cause a "community delete" by downvoting; high-rep users who are not mods can delete questions that are very downvoted.

Comment: Just to add on to that, what we usually do for spam users is "destroy" them, which deletes all content they own.

Comment: So the next time I see spam I should flag for spam and close-vote for offtopic?

Comment: @RoyT: Don't waste a close vote on it. Just flag it. If you really feel it's necessary, downvote it.